# Can QR Code Reader in mobile phone function like a Barcode Reader?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, qr-code

I try before to use a barcode reader to read a `barcodes` and it is working fine. I am thinking that how can I use QR Code Reader from my mobile phone to scan the qr code image and the scan image(data) will search in my project. In Barcode Reader I try it before but in `windows` and barcode reader is connecting to my `pc` or `laptop` how about my mobile phone how do I set it?.

BTW I am developing a asp.net mvc3 project.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no they can't.

Long answer: While the *QR reader* can't read barcodes, the app usually has some sort of barcode scanner functionality in it.

Comment: I state _I use QR Code Reader from my mobile phone to scan the qr code image_ from my post sir.

Comment: ah sorry, misinterpreted the question